# Requesting multiple ranges from Values.get results in: Unable to parse range error

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I try to get all the sheet from a spreadsheet(ID) with the Google Sheets API,
I haven't found the REST method to do that.

My code is

```
$range[]= 'sheet1!A:C';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

Array or string for $range works only if one value.
Array with mlti value give a bad url in REST:

```
$range[]= 'sheet1!A:C';
$range[]= 'SHEET2!A:C';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
```

Returns the following Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheetID]/values/Config%21A%3AC,Carte%21A%3AC?key=[my
>   api key]: (400) Unable to parse range: sheet1!A:C,SHEET2!A:C' in
>   C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www...\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www...\src\Google\Http\REST.php(62):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www...\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(174):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www....\src\Google\Http\REST.php(46):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #4 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www...\src\Google\Client.php(593):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www...\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 110

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
```

Takes a single range. You are getting an error because you are trying to send it two.

You should be calling [spreadsheet.values.batchget](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

```
<?php
/*
 * BEFORE RUNNING:
 * ---------------
 * 1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
 *    and check the quota for your project at
 *    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
 * 2. Install the PHP client library with Composer. Check installation
 *    instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.
 */

// Autoload Composer.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = getClient();

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
$spreadsheetId = '';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

$optParams = [];

// The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
$optParams['ranges'] = [];  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

// How values should be represented in the output.
// The default render option is ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE.
$optParams['valueRenderOption'] = '';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

// How dates, times, and durations should be represented in the output.
// This is ignored if value_render_option is
// FORMATTED_VALUE.
// The default dateTime render option is [DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER].
$optParams['dateTimeRenderOption'] = '';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchGet($spreadsheetId, $optParams);

// TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";

function getClient() {
  // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample
  //
  // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
  return null;
}
?>
```

Note code ripped directly from the documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)